Extracting data from Danish open data dump file in QGIS
For an interactive map, I need to create a list of all settlements, even very small ones, of Denmark (except Greenland) including name, longitude and latitude.
At first, I thought I'd extract that data from an OSM dump, but then decided to go with "official" data. After browsing some webpages of the Danish administration without knowing the Danish language, I ended up downloading an 832 MiB file called "DAR_Aktuelt_Totaludtraek_JSON_HF_20240726180006.zip" supposing it's a data dump comparable to OSM. I had hoped that all I needed to do was to drop the file on the QGIS GUI and it would come up with an overview of the content and ask me to choose. But QGIS says it's not a valid source.
Is there a simple way to get the data I need from this file into QGIS? Or should I better forget about it and use OSM?

What files are there in the zip file, what are you trying to add to QGIS?

If its a zipped JSON file it will only load into QGIS if the JSON is a special GeoJSON format. If its not then you'll have to transform it into GeoJSON or some other spatial format, and we can't help any more with that without seeing the JSON in the zip. I've had a quick look at the DAR pages (translated to English) and there's some complex database schemas going on, so it might be tricky...
